# Need help understanding a code

Tags: c#

so this program I'm on has sprites. Each sprite has a limit to the number of frames its sprite can have, and I'm trying to figure out how to learn that limit so I can modify it. But the code that I've been reading is really difficult for me. I've been reading up on some of the stuff it uses (like `Dictionary` and `Out`), but when I try to apply that reading to the code, it just falls apart.

So uh, if someone would be willing to kind of dissect the code and tell me what it says, that would be great. The full of it can be found [here](https://github.com/Frosty2011/PJOGameFiles/blob/2c0c32ec86c926ad924e0ca0dbd6fdb2bf2a8088/ServerFilesFixed/Server/Graphics/SpriteSheet.cs), but this is what I'm trying to read in particular:

```
class FrameData {
    Dictionary<FrameType, Dictionary<Enums.Direction, int>> frameCount;
}

public FrameData() {
    frameCount = new Dictionary<FrameType, Dictionary<Enums.Direction, int>>();
}

public void SetFrameCount(FrameType type, Enums.Direction dir, int count) {
    if (frameCount.ContainsKey(type) == false) {
        frameCount.Add(type, new Dictionary<Enums.Direction, int>());
    }
    if (frameCount[type].ContainsKey(dir) == false) {
        frameCount[type].Add(dir, count);
    } else {
        frameCount[type][dir] = count;
    }
}

public int GetFrameCount(FrameType type, Enums.Direction dir) {
    Dictionary<Enums.Direction, int> dirs = null;
    if (frameCount.TryGetValue(type, out dirs)) {
        int value = 0;
        if (dirs.TryGetValue(dir, out value)) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try posting question here -http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OldProgrammer This question would not be on-topic for Code Review, since it is seeking advice on how the code works.  CR is for code that already works as intended and is understood, but which you would like to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//This bit declares the class.  note that all the stuff after it should come inside the open and closed curly braces, so there's already a syntax error here. 
class FrameData {
    Dictionary<FrameType, Dictionary<Enums.Direction, int>> frameCount;
}
// Public parameterless constructor. This gets called when someone creates an instance of the class, e.g. FrameData myframe = new FrameData()
public FrameData() {
    // initialize the instance variable frameCount with a new dictionary that takes a FrameType as the key and another dictionary of Enums.Direction and ints as key and value
    frameCount = new Dictionary<FrameType, Dictionary<Enums.Direction, int>>();
}
// Public method for adding or replacing a key and its value in the frameCount dictionary
public void SetFrameCount(FrameType type, Enums.Direction dir, int count) {
    // adds a new one if it didn't already have that key
    if (frameCount.ContainsKey(type) == false) {
        frameCount.Add(type, new Dictionary<Enums.Direction, int>());
    }
    // adds a new key to the inner dictionary if it's not there
    if (frameCount[type].ContainsKey(dir) == false) {
        frameCount[type].Add(dir, count);
    } else {
        // otherwise just replaces what was already there
        frameCount[type][dir] = count;
    }
}
// fetches the nested value from the inner dictionary given the type and direction
public int GetFrameCount(FrameType type, Enums.Direction dir) {
    Dictionary<Enums.Direction, int> dirs = null;
    if (frameCount.TryGetValue(type, out dirs)) {
        int value = 0;
        if (dirs.TryGetValue(dir, out value)) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I guess this probably won't be what sets how many frames a spritesheet can have, then... Time to sift through more files x: